# Invoking Powershell within default.aspx.vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, powershell

I'm looking for some help with my default.aspx.vb script. I have a webpage which an end user will enter an ID and a file, which uploads into a directory.

I have Powershell script which I have converted into a module, and additionally i have an module for launching Exchange Server 2010 Powershell.

Although the uploaded file is uploaded correctly, the second part to run the powershell commmand, seems to not work, and this is captured by the exception.

Looking for advice to why the latter half of the code fails

Thanks

Comment: Does it fail on the pipe.Invoke() ? What is the error?

Comment: After it uploads the file in the specific directory, the script just goes to the exception message. How can I trap errors? 

I'm lost to why it would not invoke, I wasn't sure if what was written in aspx.vb is correct ??

Comment: Does the code look correct. I'm running this on Windows 2008 r2 & iis 7.0? I do receive a first error acception error in the debug of visual studio.

Comment: You won't help yourself until you investigate what is the error. Use the Message property,  and evaluate .GetType().Name to at least see what's happening. Update the question with your findings.

Comment: The last comment was concerned with the Exception class

Comment: Ok I'll try that this afternoon. Although it's hard I am enjoying learning more about how to troubleshoot this issue. Thanks.

Comment: The thread 'Pipeline Execution Thread' (0x20ac) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Pipeline Execution Thread' (0x20b8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Pipeline Execution Thread' (0x20c4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
A first chance exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll
The thread '<No Name>' (0xe08) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: These are the debug errors i see in visual studio? what do they indicate? ----- The thread 'Pipeline Execution Thread' (0x20ac) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Pipeline Execution Thread' (0x20b8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Pipeline Execution Thread' (0x20c4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
A first chance exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll
The thread '<No Name>' (0xe08) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your further comments mention that the underlying error is a CommandNotFoundException. Which means just that. Looking at the Powershell command you are trying to execute, it is the following:

```
Dim pscommand As Command = New Command("MailboxReport -SAID" & r & "-TXTPATH" & q)
```

If you look carefully, unless `r` has a space before and  after it, the resulting command will be something like:

```
"MailboxReport -SAID11364-TXTPATHC:\WHATEVER"
```

Comment: is there a way to create spaces within vb strings? Would it be something like this - Dim pscommand As Command = New Command("MailboxReport -SAID " & r & "-TXTPATH " & q)?

Comment: Dim pscommand As Command = New Command("MailboxReport -SAID " & r & " -TXTPATH " & q) The thread '<No Name>' (0x2054) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Pipeline Execution Thread' (0x213c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x190c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Pipeline Execution Thread' (0x228c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Pipeline Execution Thread' (0xdf4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
A first chance exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll

Comment: Dim q As String = physicalFolder.ToString
Dim r As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim firstString As String
Dim secondString As String
Dim startString As String
firstString = "-SAID"
secondString = "-TXTPATH"
firstString = firstString & " "
secondString = secondString & " "
firstString = firstString & r
secondString = secondString & q
firstString = firstString & " "
startString =”MailboxReport”
startString=startString & “ “
Dim pipe As Pipeline = rs.CreatePipeline()
Dim pscommand As Command = New Command(startString &  firstString  &  secondString)
pipe.Commands.Add(pscommand)
pipe.Invoke()

Comment: I found the issue, the ps modules required are not loading. My error log file came back with the following error. Fatal error : The term 'MailboxReport -SAID admin -TXTPATH D:\Reports\uploads\08156-20140427-145235-719' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again., please find a complete error at ErrorLog file.

Comment: How do I get the aspx page load the powershell modules?

Comment: Couldn't you load the powershell modules from the powershell scripts using Import-Module? Maybe you are using Powershell 3.0 scripts? That version auto-loads modules which contain commandlets you are using. Maybe that doesn't work when being added via the .NET programming interface?

Comment: I checked the ps version it is running under a 2.0 shell. For none of either snap in's or modules to be entered into the configuration suggests the powershell configuration I'm using is not correct. I guess. I'm stuck with this one.